# CMake errors in CLion when using for WSL

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clion, wsl-2

I am seeing errors in CLion for WSL2

```
CMake error at usr/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:188 (file): file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

CMake Error: Could not open file for write in copy operation files/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/3.21.0/CMakeSystem.cmake.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:334 (file):
  file problem creating directory:

...
....
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: cmake-build-debug/CMakeCache.txt.tmp035f3
CMake Error: : System Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
CMake Error: Unable to open cache file for save. cmake-build-debug/CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: : System Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I tried:

- adding a wsl.conf file

```
# /etc/wsl.conf
[automount]
options = "metadata"
enabled = true
```

- shutting down WSL by running the following command

```
wsl --shutdown
```

but then refreshing CLion says

```
Cannot save file \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\CMakeFiles\clion-environment.txt
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar situation.

My Windows user is administrator, so I suspect that WSL has insufficient permissions, and I tried to switch the default user of WSL to root.

```
ubuntu config --default-user root
```

The following image shows the state of CLion after I switched to root.
[CLion status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyDT2.png)

There are still errors, but it can detect CMake and I can now use CMake to build the program.

Lastly, here is my original error message.

```
CMake Error: Could not open file for write in copy operation /mnt/c/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment1/_build9958369055144970030/CMakeFiles/3.22.1/CMakeSystem.cmake.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:193 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)

...
....

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:56 (try_compile):
  Unknown extension ".c" for file

    /mnt/c/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment1/_build9958369055144970030/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

  try_compile() works only for enabled languages.  Currently these are:

    C CXX

  See project() command to enable other languages.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   

 

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```